# How to extract Mono from argument type to the upper level?

Tags: java, functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Having a function `myFunc`, which returns a `Mono`, is it possible to convert it to a Mono of function, that behaves like if it extracts internally the value from Mono?

```
Function<A, Mono<B>> myFunc = createMyFunction(....);

                                 /* how this decorator works? */
Mono<Function<A, B> myFuncMono = magicDecorator(myFunc);
```

Please, give some thoughts on how do we write the function `magicDecorator`.

UPDATE:

If this looks impossible, let us consider a simpler problem.
How to convert `List<Mono<String>>` to `Mono<List<String>>`?

Actually, I am trying to understand if a "reactive" nature of an argument can be propagated upper: i.e. from list elements to the list itself, from function result to the function itself.

Comment: No. Java does not have reified generic types. There is type erasure to contend with. And your "working" decorator doesn't, there is at least one typo there and you haven't shown us `magicDecorator` (but it probably can't be done in Java).

Comment: @Elliott Yes, that's the problem - I do not understand how to write the `magicDecorator`. So I'm curious, is it impossible or I just cannot figure it out. Updated the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: You can't do this, each individual mono would have it's own flow,subscription etc, which couldn't all be amalgamated into one.